# Show every nonempty compact Hausdorff space is not the countable union of nowhere dense sets

Tags: general-topology, compactness, baire-category

I know this proof is somewhat similar, or related to the Baire's Category Theorem but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

The Baire Category theorem asserts that if X is a complete metric space or a locally compact Hausdorff space (my case), then the complement of a countable union of nowhere dense sets is always nonempty.

How can I use this on the proof?

Answer (score 2):

Since every compact Hausdorff space is locally compact, you can actually *use* the statement that you mentioned.